# How do I declare an array of objects within it's own class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, declare

I am unsure how to create an array of objects within its own class. For example:

```
class A { 
public:
  const static int MAX_SIZE = 10;

 private:
  A arrayOfOBjects[MAX_SIZE];


}
```

I get an error saying, "incomplete type is now allowed" How would I go about this? If I declare an array of objects from another class inside Class A it will work.. But how do I create an array of objects within its own class?

Comment: A class cannot contains members of its own type. You would need to hold an array of smart pointers to `A`.

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16756876/2040040

Comment: @juanchopanza What about `std::array<A, MAX_SIZE>`?

Comment: @PeterWood that shouldn't work either. But `std::vector<A>` could.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah, it's an incomplete type. Yes, `vector` would work.

Comment: @PeterWood correct. `std::array` poses the same problems as a standard fixed size C array, which is the same problem as having a single data member of type `A` within `A`. `std::vector` does not have that problem, because it allocates `A` objects dynamically and does not need to have the complete `A` type (although I am sure this hasn't worked in older compilers I have used).

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, some compilers it didn't work, also for the key/value pair of a `map`. I always thought it was a leaky implementation detail though. Why can't `array` be implemented like `vector`?

Comment: @PeterWood because `std::array` is a no-overhead drop-in replacement for a fixed size C array, so all the data it holds is its elements. It cannot have a pointer that points to some dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

use a pointer. or shared_ptr etc and dynamically allocate the objects

```
class A { 
public:
  const static int MAX_SIZE = 10;

 private:
  A * arrayOfOBjects[MAX_SIZE];


}
```

Comment: Where do you see a requirement for shared ownership semantics?

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't contain an instance of the object in itself. It would take infinite amount of storage ;-)

For the same reason you can't contain several. Maybe you meant the array to be a static member that doesn't add to the state of one instance?

Answer (score 0):

By using pointers you can solve this problem

```
class A { 
public:
  const static int MAX_SIZE = 10;
  void allocate(){
     arrayOfOBjects=new A[MAX_SIZE];
  }
 private:
  A *arrayOfOBjects;
};
```

You can use this as following

```
A a;
a.allocate();
```